# Nested for loop confusion with .format()

Tags: python, html, loops, for-loop, nested

Desired output:

```
<ul> 
<li>first string</li>
<li>second string</li>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
items = ['first string', 'second string']
html_str = "<ul>\n"          # The "\n" here is the end-of-line char, causing
                             # chars after this in html_str to be on next line

for item in items:
html_str += "<li>{}</li>\n".format(item)
html_str += "</ul>"

print(html_str)
```

For the code above, I am confused about why

```
</ul>
```

only appears once, instead of twice. In other words, it is not clear to me why the middle two lines ("first string" and "second string") is looped twice, and the last line is only displayed once.

Comment: The code seems to be fine - but how is it indented? What's in the loop, and what's out?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue was with indentation of the for loop. The correct code should be:

```
items = ['first string', 'second string']
html_str = "<ul>\n"          # The "\n" here is the end-of-line char, causing
                             # chars after this in html_str to be on next line

for item in items:
    html_str += "<li>{}</li>\n".format(item)
html_str += "</ul>"

print(html_str)
```

I was reminded about the importance of indentation in programming.

Comment: @Gabip Thank you for the correct term - indentation.